# How do I sort elements of value of dictionary which is a single list and having it has few nested lists?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Dictionary is like this

```
some_dict={Shape:[ ["red",9,6],["blue",9,6],["green",9,6] ] }
```

It should be sorted by using first element of nested lists

```
some_dict={Shape:[ ["blue",9,6],["green",9,6],["red",9,6] ] }
```

So the dictionary has just one key and one value i.e. list and that list contains multiple nested lists.

I have done something like this but I don't want to remove and append as it is causing error in project.

```
if flag2==0:
        tempLL=sorted(tempL, key = lambda x: x[0],reverse=False)
        if flag3==1: #if only 2 elements in dict
            shapes['Circle']=[]
            flag3=0

        for x in range (0,lengthOfShape):
            shapes['Circle'].append(tempLL[x])
```

Please note I am not supposed to import any libraries
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `sorted`
It can take a key param which can specify what the comparison should be made on.

Ex:

```
shapeList = [["red",9,6],["blue",9,6],["green",9,6]]
sorted(shapeList, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

results in:
`[['blue', 9, 6], ['green', 9, 6], ['red', 9, 6]]`

if you are trying to modify and replace the information in the dictionary with the updated values, you can easily do

```
some_dict['Shape'] = some_dict(dict['Shape'], key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: did this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be a little application specific so I didn't include anything not related to sorting lists.

The following sorts your list of lists by the first element. Seems like you may have already been doing this.

```
def sortByFirst(lists):
   return sorted(lists, lambda x: x[0])
```

What we are doing here is telling the sorted function that it will compare the first element of the sub-lists. This function will return a list of lists, sorted in order of the first element.